# Problems with comparing and appending strings to each other c++

Tags: c++, string, append

I'm writing some code, and what it's supposed to do is return the path to a file without the filename itself. Here it is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char binaryPath[MAX_PATH]; //I think my problems stem from the fact that 
                               //isnt truly a string

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, binaryPath, MAX_PATH); //Get filename
    string i = (string) binaryPath;
    string fileDir = "";
    int tempSlashes = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(binaryPath); x++) {
        if (i[x] == '\\') { //In eclipse CDT this gives warning 1 (below)
            tempSlashes++; 
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < tempSlashes; y++) {
        fileDir.append(binaryPath[y]); //Line gives warning 2
    }
    cout << fileDir;
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, the little warning annotations

```
Error 1:
Multiple markers at this line
- comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-
 Waddress]
- ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-
 fpermissive]

Error 2:
Multiple markers at this line
- Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const 
 std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &) std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const 
 std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, unsigned int) std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const 
 char *, unsigned int) std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(const char *) std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & 
 append(unsigned int, char) std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & append(#10000, #10000) '
- invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

The program itself refuses to compile, and runs an earlier .exe

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and help (as well as an explanation) would be very nice.

Thanks!

Comment: My original answer was wrong. But [here is a fixed version of your code](http://ideone.com/RjVVkH) (although there are better ways to do this).

Comment: I just wanted to code it myself. Oh also, another question. I'm trying to pass the a string named s to an os command like this:                 system("cd "+s)                                                              but Eclipse is complaining that It                                          - cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int 
  system(const char*)'                                        
 - And That i'm also giving it:                         Invalid arguments                       EDIT: Solved by calling s.c_str();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest iterating backward and looking for '\'. Something like:

```
int len = strlen(binaryPath);
char outPath[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(outPath, binaryPath);
for (int x = len - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
    outPath[x] = 0;
    if (binaryPath[x] == '\\') {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in modern Win32 C++ code you may want to use **Unicode** instead of ANSI/MBCS (so, `wchar_t` instead of `char`, and `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`).

For your particular question, you may want to use an existing Win32 API: [**PathRemoveFileSpec()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a sample compilable code:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

int main()
{
    wchar_t binaryPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(nullptr, binaryPath, MAX_PATH);
    PathRemoveFileSpec(binaryPath);

    // You can assign to a std::wstring as well...
    wstring fileDir = binaryPath;

    wcout << fileDir << endl;
}
```

Here is a sample test:

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /MTd test.cpp
> test.cpp
>
> C:\Temp\CppTests>test.exe
> C:\Temp\CppTests
> ```

---

As an alternative, once you have the full path with file name read in the raw C buffer:

```
wchar_t binaryPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(nullptr, binaryPathBuffer, MAX_PATH);
```

you can copy it in a `std::wstring`, and then use its **`rfind()`** method to find the position of the last `'\'`, and then extract the proper substring using **`substr`** method of `std::wstring`:

```
wstring binaryPath = binaryPathBuffer;
size_t last = binaryPath.rfind(L'\\');
wstring fileDir = binaryPath.substr(0, last);
```